# User Input not being taken? Batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd, command-prompt

I've been making this code for an unofficial coding class of mine when one of my students ran into a problem where the process just ends task every time one of the expected answers is taken. I checked his code over and over again, and don't see where the problem is.

```
    @echo off
rem Everywhere you see "rem" as a command is simply developer notes to help keep track of what and where everything is. Deleting all rem commands will not affect the program.
if not exist "C:\Program Files\Led\Ping Testor\version\1.7.info" goto new
if exist "C:\Program Files\Led\Ping Testor\version\1.7.info" goto old
rem Checks for first-time launch on local machine.

:new
if not exist "C:\Program Files\Led"
(
cd "C:\Program Files\"
md Led
)
if not exist "C:\Program Files\Led\Ping Testor"
(
cd "C:\Program Files\Led"
md "Ping Testor"
)
if not exist "C:\Program Files\Led\Ping Testor\version"
(
cd "C:\Program Files\Led\Ping Testor\"
md "version"
)
if not exist "C:\Program Files\Led\Ping Testor\version\1.7.info"
(
cd "C:\Program Files\Led\Ping Testor\version"
echo "1.7235 Release. Beta Officially Closed. More Information at LedDevelopment.CU.CC/main/products/led-ping-testor" >1.7.info
)
goto old
rem Creates all necessary directories if they don't exist and adds version information to the directory.

:old
title Led Development AB 2015 - 2016
color 0a
mode con: cols=65 lines=18
cls
rem Window setup (Initial).

:a
echo Led Ping Testor                                        v1.7235(R)   
rem The (R) after the version number indicates state/build type. (R) in this case means release, as in finished product. (B) is for Beta (Used for testing and developing by both users and proffessional developers), and there's (A) which is the essentials of the code for the program to function at all(Led Development Team Only).Occasionally, an (E) (evaluation copy) is developed.
echo ===============                                        ==========
echo Welcome to the Led Ping Testor. Please choose 1 to test your pingto our official website server or 2 to test your connection to a custom IP Address/Website. If you don't understand any of this,  choose option 1.
echo.
echo NOTE: A log file keeps track of all the ping results,as well as  time and date,but no personal information is kept,including your IP Address or computer name. To view the log file,type "log"     without the quotation marks and hit enter. Similarly,if you wish to clear the log of all data,type "logclr" without the quotation marks and hit enter.
rem Intro text.

set /p op=
if %op%== 1 goto ping1
if %op%== 2 goto ping2a
if %op%== log goto log
if %op%== logclr goto logclr
rem This checks for all eligible user input for this stage.
goto old
rem This takes user back to Main Screen in case of non-eligible input.

:log
cls
if exist "C:\Program Files\Led\Ping Testor\log.txt"
(
cd "C:\Program Files\Led\Ping Testor\"
start log.txt
)
rem Opens log if exists.

if not exist "C:\Program Files\Led\Ping Testor\log.txt"
(
cls
echo The log file is empty, thus cannot be openned.
pause
goto a
)
rem Gives error message if log doesn't exist.


:logclr
cls
cd "C:\Program Files\Led\Ping Testor\"
del log.txt
goto old

:ping1
echo Please choose how many times you want to ping the host.
set /p %numb%
if %numb% < 1 goto ping1a
if %numb% > 99999 goto ping1a
rem Checks if user input was between 1 and 99999 to confirm user input as an interger (numbers only).
cls
rem If user input isn't an integer between 1 and 99999, error message explaining appears in a new  window.
msg %username% Warning: Not a numerical value between 1 and 99999. Please check your spelling and remove all letters, special characters and spaces.
goto ping1

:ping1a
cls
title Pinging 185.28.21.39...
cls
cd "C:\Program Files\Led\Ping Testor\"
echo ========================================================= >>log.txt
echo Host:185.28.21.39          Ping Count:%numb% >>log.txt
echo Include this in any bug reports for the Ping Testor. >>log.txt
echo %date% >> log.txt
rem All this chunck of code above is the injection of data to the log file.

:ping11
echo Led Ping Testor
echo ===============
echo The ping is called time, and is displayed upon every loop.
echo.
ping 185.28.21.39 -n %numb% >>log.txt
ping 185.28.21.39 -n %numb%
ping localhost -n 2 >nul
cls
goto ping11
rem And this chunck performs the same thing as above but infront of the user.
```

The problem is here:

```
echo Welcome to the Led Ping Testor. Please choose 1 to test your pingto our official website server or 2 to test your connection to a custom IP Address/Website. If you don't understand any of this,  choose option 1.
echo.
echo NOTE: A log file keeps track of all the ping results,as well as  time and date,but no personal information is kept,including your IP Address or computer name. To view the log file,type "log"     without the quotation marks and hit enter. Similarly,if you wish to clear the log of all data,type "logclr" without the quotation marks and hit enter.
rem Intro text.

set /p op=
if %op%== 1 goto ping1
if %op%== 2 goto ping2a
if %op%== log goto log
if %op%== logclr goto logclr
rem This checks for all eligible user input for this stage.
goto old
rem This takes user back to Main Screen in case of non-eligible input.
```

Yes, I know the :ping2 still doesn't exist because i didn't add it to this code yet, but none of the existing commands work either, like ping1 (by pressing 1), log and logclr. Logclr, sometimes, just seems to kind of "refresh" the screen.
Thanks for your help in advance. I will add the person's name to the credits somewhere along the lines. Maybe on the website (leddevelopment.cu.cc/main/products/led-ping-testor/).

Comment: Get rid of the space after `==`

Comment: Didn't work for me. It still exits when i hit enter.

Answer (score 1):

Not clear what you mean by "work". The second piece of code "work"ed for me - that is, did what I expected it to do.

Since you have not invoked `setlocal`, any settings made during earlier runs will remain in the environment. Perhaps that is a cause.

If you use `if "%var%"=="string" ...` then you are protected somewhat agains the user entering spaces. You could also try `if /i ...` for case-insensitivity.

Your `if %numb% < 1 goto ping1a` will not work as `<` and `>` are redirectors. you'd need to use `lss` and `gtr` respectively.

Please explain what is meant to happen and what actually happens if these clues don't solve your problem.

Comment: The first part of the code that I claimed didn't work did not actually take me to the specified location like ping1. It just closes the program everytime.

Comment: And i was trying to force the input to be an integer as supposed to a string to be able to use it in a command( talking about 'if %numb% < 1 goto ping1a' and 'if %numb% < 99999 goto ping1a')

Comment: The code worked for me as-is wrt the switching to the specified location. You should run the code from the command prompt and comment-out the `@echo off` to get a trace of precisely what is happening. You should be able to resolve the matter from there. As for the comparisons, I repeat `<` and `>` are redirectors. you'd need to use `lss` and `gtr` respectively.

Comment: I changed the redirectors as of your advice (thanks for that). It still stops dead in it's tracks and closes every time. I tried turning on echo but the file closes the same way. I even tried adding a pause after all of the :s (ping1, ping2a, log and logclr) to see if i get an error report but Nothing! it still closes on me before i can see anything.

Comment: Unfortunately, it seems you are still not running from the command prompt which whould show you an error message. From your comment `It still exits when i hit enter.` I can only conclude that you are simply pressing `enter` when prompted, which will make `%op%` empty, so batch will interpret  `if %op%== 1 ...` as `if == 1...` which is a syntax error. Use `if "%op%"=="1"...`

Comment: I meant it in the sense that I type in 1 and press enter but it still closes.

Comment: Shouldn't opening parentheses be on the same line as the if they belong to?

Comment: Certainly should - that might fix a couple of problems up... `if` and `(` must be on the same physical line.